# Inorder function for Binary Search Tree implementation not working for global structure pointer

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have written this piece of code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct nd{
   int data;
   struct nd *left;
   struct nd *right;
};

struct nd *root = NULL;

void create_tree(){
   int key;
   printf("Enter a value that you want to insert-\n");
   scanf("%d", &key);
   insert(key);
 }

 void insert(int key){
    struct nd *temp, *follow, *p;
    temp=(struct nd*)malloc(sizeof(struct nd));

 //If malloc doesn't allocate space and returns NULL then print the reason
 if(temp == NULL){
   printf("Memory overflow!");
   return;
 }

 temp->data = key;
 temp->left = temp->right = NULL;


 if(root == NULL){
    root=temp;
 }else{
   p=root;
    follow=NULL;
     while(p!=NULL){
         follow=p;
         if(temp->data<p->data){
            p=p->left;
       }else{
           p=p->right;
       }
   }

   if(temp->data<follow->data){
       follow->left=temp;
   }else{
       follow->right=temp;
   }
  }

   printf("\nInsertion Successful!\n");

}

void inorder(){

 if(root!=NULL){
      inorder(root->left);
      printf("%d",root->data);
      inorder(root->right);
  }

}
void main(){
  create_tree();
  create_tree();
  create_tree();
  create_tree();

  inorder();
}
```

This code doesn't output the inorder traversal data. But if I change the inorder() function call in main() function to this-

```
  inorder(root);
```

and give the function a parameter like this-

```
void inorder(struct nd *root){

 if(root!=NULL){
      inorder(root->left);
      printf("%d",root->data);
      inorder(root->right);
  }

}
```

suddenly, it gives the expected output i.e it shows the inorder traversal data for the created tree.But since root variable is defined as a global variable, my question is why do we have to pass that root variable to the inorder function? since root is a global variable then all the functions get access to that variable, right? So I cannot understand why this is happening.

Comment: What does your compiler have to say about the problematic code?

Comment: I got 2 or 3 implicit type conversion warning but nothing that would affect the code during compilation and runtime. But I understood where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatch in inorder function signature
in the definition it is () but inside the function you are calling it with arguments

Signature : void inorder()
call :      inorder(root->left);

Comment: I understand what the problem was now. Thank you :D